# Confusing text-align issues

Tags: css, text-align

I am working on a website that helps people become more aware of the threats posed by the internet.

I have bumped into a VERY annoying css problem where the text will not center horizontally or vertically and generally doesn't seem to listen to the css properly. I have checked for anything overriding it and there's nothing.

http://nblackburn.me/pofa/

Comment: I think everything centered? I couldn't understand problem

Comment: The only thing that is centered is the main div named "content", unless thats causing the issue then i have no idea.

Comment: Fixed it now, it was it was a span and spans are only ever the width of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're centering the text within the span, which isn't working because the span is only the size of the text. You need to either use a `p` element and use `text-align:center` with that, or add `text-align:center` to the parent of the span.

For aligning vertically, you can set the parent of an element to `display:table;` and the element to `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;`. This will vertically align the element.

Comment: Thanks dude, i knew it was something simple.

Comment: dsiplay:table only works in recent browsers.  It won't work in IE7.

Comment: @MystereMan, Damn, at this point I just assume things don't work in any version of IE ever. Do you happen to know of anything that aligns vertically that works in IE7

Comment: @Walkerneo - It's not a simple problem.  The easiest solution, if it works for you is to set height and line-height to the same size.  That only works for text though.  See http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

`display: block;` and `line-height:200px` on `.sopa-box .title` will center both horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I see in your CSS:

```
.sopa-box .title {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #111111;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Heres what it should be:

```
.title {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #111111;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That way when you use:

```
<div class="sopa-box">
     <span class="title">SOPA</span>
</div>
```

You wont have any problems.